# Mailer config in Craft 3 not getting merged

Tags: emails, craft3, craft-pro

I have this custom config in config/app.php,
but Craft seems to keep using the default Control panel Sendmail config.

It seems this doesn't get merged in the main.php file. (as promised)

```
 return [
 'components' => [
     'mailer' => function() {

        // Get the stored email settings
        $settings = Craft::$app->systemSettings->getEmailSettings();

        // Override the transport adapter class
        $settings->transportType = craft\mail\transportadapters\Smtp::class;

        // Override the transport adapter settings
        $settings->transportSettings = [
            'host' => 'xx',
            'port' => 'xx',
            'useAuthentication' => true,
            'username' => 'xx',
            'password' => 'xx'
        ];

        return craft\helpers\MailerHelper::createMailer($settings);
     },
 ],
```

];

Comment: Check out https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2554#issuecomment-407713430

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked is instantiating and returning a Craft object, see below:
Also, you might want to consider abstracting away env variables.
I am using Craft 4

```
return [

    'id' => App::env('CRAFT_APP_ID') ?: 'CraftCMS',

    'modules' => [

        'my-module' => \modules\Module::class,

    ],

    'components' => [

        'mailer' => function() {



            $settings = craft\helpers\App::mailSettings();

            $settings->fromEmail = craft\helpers\App::env('CONTACT_FROM_EMAIL');

            // Override the transport adapter class
            $settings->transportType = craft\mail\transportadapters\Smtp::class;

            // Override the transport adapter settings
            $settings->transportSettings = [

                'host' => craft\helpers\App::env('SMTP_HOST'),

                'port' => craft\helpers\App::env('SMTP_PORT'),

                'useAuthentication' => true,

                'username' => craft\helpers\App::env('SMTP_USERNAME'),

                'password' => craft\helpers\App::env('SMTP_PASSWORD')

            ];


            
            // Create a Mailer component config with these settings
            $config = craft\helpers\App::mailerConfig($settings);

            // Instantiate and return it
            return Craft::createObject($config);

        }
    ]
   
];
```

Answer (score 1):

This was addressed in [this issue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2554) and the `MailerHelper::createMailer()` method was deprecated as of Craft 3.0.18, `App::mailerConfig()` should be used instead.

Changelog: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/v3/CHANGELOG.md#3018---2018-07-31

Here's a working version for Craft 3.1.0 and above.

```php
<?php

use craft\helpers\App;
use craft\mail\transportadapters\Smtp;

return [
    'components' => [
        'mailer' => function() {
            // Get the stored email settings
            $settings = App::mailSettings();

            // Override the transport adapter class
            $settings->transportType = Smtp::class;

            // Override the transport adapter settings
            $settings->transportSettings = [
                'host' => 'xx',
                'port' => 'xx',
                'useAuthentication' => true,
                'username' => 'xx',
                'password' => 'xx'
            ];

            $config = App::mailerConfig($settings);
            return Craft::createObject($config);
        }
    ],
];
```